# ¿Cómo Validar un número de télefono?

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

Buen día comunidad, acudo a ustedes para que me ayuden en lo siguiente.

requiero validar un número de teléfono que sea de esta manera +582123216969

Debe tener el +58 seguido del código de area (212,424,414,416,426) estos son 3 números, seguido del código de area vienen 7 números que pueden ser de 0-9.

Mi función o expresión regular es la siguiente:

```
function capturarTelefono(){
    let valorCampo= document.getElementById('my_id');
    let expreReg = /[+58][\d(424|414|426|416|212)]{3}\d[0-9]{7}/;

    if(!expreReg.test(valorCampo)){
        console.log('Hay error');
    }else{
        console.log('Todo bien');
    }
    
}
```

Acá es dónde llamo a la función:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 p-0 m-0">
  <div class="form-group p-0 px-1  m-0">
      <?php echo $this->Form->control('phone', [ 'id' => 'phone', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control','type' => 'tel', 'onkeypress' => 'capturarTelefono()', 'required']); ?>
   </div>
 </div>
```

No se, si mi expresión regular esta mal hecha o cual podria ser el error que tengo.

Les agradezco de antemano cualquier orientación.

Comment: Estas declarando la variable como `expreReg` y luego estás validando con `expreRegu`. Ahí hay una pequeña discrepancia.

Comment: @DjCrazy tienes razón, pero fue error al colocar o pegar el código. Aún sigue el problema inicial.

Comment: @kevinrojas revertí mi respuesta, pruébalo y me dices si está correcto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la siguiente expresión regular validas que el número tenga el símbolo `+` al inicio y que tenga la longitud de números de teléfono (en este caso, 12 números). También verifica si el número de teléfono empieza con `+58`, sería lo siguiente:

```js
function capturarTelefono(valorCampo) {
  expreReg = /[+][58][\d(424|414|426|416|212)]{3}\d[0-9]{7}$/;
  
  if (expreReg.test(valorCampo) && (valorCampo.substring(0,3) === '+58')) {
    return 'Es número telefónico';
  } else {
    return 'No es número telefónico';
  }
}

console.log(capturarTelefono('+582123216969')); // correcto
console.log(capturarTelefono('+572123216969')); // número con +57 => incorrecto
console.log(capturarTelefono('582123216969')); // misma longitud pero sin el "+" => incorrecto
console.log(capturarTelefono('+5821232169')); // menos números => incorrecto
console.log(capturarTelefono('+58212321696934')); // más números => incorrecto
```

Comment: me parecio interesante la respuesta, la probé y funciona para lo que requiero, gracias.